# Running prototype functions after function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prototype

I'm trying to learn a bit more about javascript prototypes (I guess that's what this is called). I saw some NodeJS modules with functions being called like this: `something.funcA().funcB().funcC();` and I am trying to reproduce it. How can I do it and how's it called?

This is what I got so far from trying:

```
var total = { t: 0 };

module.exports.calculate = function() {
    var calc = {};

    calc.result = function result() {
        return total.t;
    }

    calc.add = function add(num) {
        total.t += num;
        return this;
    }

    calc.sub = function sub(num) {
        total.t -= num;
        return this;
    }

    return calc;
};
```

When I call the function:

```
calc = require('../helpers/calculate');

// 5 - 1 + 3 = 7
calc.calculate().add(5).sub(1);
calc.calculate().add(3);

console.log(calc.calculate().result());
```

Running `add()` works but not when I run `sub()` after `add()`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of undefined
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with prototypes; it's just a normal function that returns a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add(5).sub(1)` calls `sub()` on the object returned by `add()`.

Since `add()` doesn't return anything, that won't work.

You probably want to return `this`.

Comment: `TypeError: calc.calculate(...).add(...).sub is not a function` after adding `return this;` to both functions.

Comment: Using `return this;` made it work for me. Can you update the code in your question to what you currently have?

Comment: I believe `this` is going to be `calc` in this case. It seems to run fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/QblxBas.png . OP, are you sure that you're requiring the right file?

Comment: I had this in my code: `calc.add = function sub(num) {`. Of course it wouldn't work. Thanks a lot for the help.